# How do i add numbers to variables?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x

So, i have been trying to build a python number guessing game. I am new, and i can't figure out how i add +1 to my chance variable. I have tried +=1 like here but it always shows 1 as the output no matter what. And i know that there is a lot of things wrong with this code but, keep in mind that i am new to coding.

```py
import random

numbers = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 
user = None
hidden = random.choice(numbers)

print("Welcome to volty's's number guessing game!")
def game():
  chance = 0
  user = int(input("choose a number from 1 to 10: "))
  if user > hidden:
    print ("ur number is more than the hidden number")
    game()
    chance += 1
  elif user < hidden: 
   print ("ur number is less than the hidden number")
   game()
   chance = +1
  elif user == hidden:
    print (" u guessed the hidden number!")
    print ("the hidden number was:",hidden)
    print (f"u guessed it in {chance +1} step {'s' if chance > 1 else ' '}")
  
game()
```

So this is the code.

Comment: Where you have: `chance += 1` this will increment your variable. However, you have several other problems which defeats this effect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many things wrong with this code, which makes it not possible to extract a clear question. Please read [ask] and note well that this is not a tutorial service; we do not make code work here, but instead we answer single, specific questions that come out of your best attempt to resolve the problem yourself. Sometimes, this means that beginners will not be able to ask the question they need answered (because they don't yet know enough in order to identify problems and choose one). Therefore, please try an actual **discussion forum** such as Reddit or Quora.

Comment: "_And i know that there is a lot of things wrong with this code but, keep in mind that i am new to coding._" That doesn't mean you don't have to do basic research or first try debugging your program. Your literal question ("_How do I add numbers to variables?") can be answered with `a += 1`, and you seem to already know that. However, you re-assign the value 0 to your variable and you have a typo (`chance = +1` should be `chance +=1`). By debugging your code or by printing the value, you would easily find out yourself. That is why a [mre] is generally requested here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Whenever `game` is invoked, the variable is set to 0. It is incremented at at most one place in the function body (only if `user 1= hidden`), so it is set to 1 in those cases, but each recursive call to `game` gets its own copy of this variable, which is reset to 0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution : shift you "chance = 0" outside the function scope start.

Reason: every time your code gets inside the if statement it re-initialized the chance value to 0.

Comment: print will still never show an incremented chance...

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the variable `chance` to the function when you call it. You can then increment `chance` directly when you recursively call upon the function:

```
import random

numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
user = None
hidden = random.choice(numbers)

print("Welcome to volty's's number guessing game!")

chance = 0

def game(chance):
    user = int(input("choose a number from 1 to 10: "))
    if user > hidden:
        print("ur number is more than the hidden number")
        game(chance + 1)
        # chance += 1
    elif user < hidden:
        print("ur number is less than the hudden number")
        game(chance + 1)
        # chance += 1
    elif user == hidden:
        print(" u guessed the hidden number!")
        print("the hidden number was:", hidden)
        print(f"u guessed it in {chance + 1} step{'s' if chance > 1 else ' '}")


game(chance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your big issue here is the way you are using recursion. The awnser is simple:
change your variable before recursing

```
import random

numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
user = None
hidden = random.choice(numbers)

print("Welcome to volty's's number guessing game!")


def game(chance):
    user = int(input("choose a number from 1 to 10: "))
    if user > hidden:
        print("ur number is more than the hidden number")
        chance += 1
        game(chance)
    elif user < hidden:
        print("ur number is less than the hudden number")
        chance += 1
        game(chance)
    elif user == hidden:
        print(" u guessed the hidden number!")
        print("the hidden number was:", hidden)
        print(f"u guessed it in {chance + 1} step {'s' if chance > 1 else ' '}")


game(0)
```

Checkout a tutorial about recursion

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have to re-call the function "game()" every time you fail.
Ideally you should create the condition "is_hidden_found" which is true ONLY if the player succeeds in finding the number.
Thus, the same variables are used until the win and "chance" is incremented.

```py
import random

print("Welcome to volty's's number guessing game!")
def game():
  numbers = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 
  user = None
  hidden = random.choice(numbers) # maybe use random.randint(0, 10)

  is_hidden_found = False
  chance = 0
  while is_hidden_found == False:

    user = int(input("choose a number from 1 to 10: "))
    if user > hidden:
      print ("ur number is more than the hidden number")
      chance += 1
    elif user < hidden: 
     print ("ur number is less than the hudden number")
     chance += 1
    elif user == hidden:
      is_hidden_found = True
      print (" u guessed the hidden number!")
      print ("the hidden number was:",hidden)
      print (f"u guessed it in {chance +1} step {'s' if chance > 1 else ' '}")

game()
```

Have fun while you learn ;)